# does malloc guarantee to allocate only the assigned memory block?

Tags: c, malloc

I have assigned memory only for 4 integer in below program but the program when compiled/built with gcc 7.4.0 is not crashing. Is it because memory next to those assigned 4*4 bytes were not being used when I ran the built exe?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int *p = malloc(4*sizeof(int)); //allocating for only 4 integers
    if(NULL != p)
    {
        p[0] = 13;
        p[1] = 24;
        p[2] = 35;
        p[3] = 46;
        p[4] = 57;
        p[76] = 67;
        p[100] = 32;
        printf("%d %d %d %d %d %d %d", p[0], p[1], p[2], p[3], p[4], p[76], p[100]); //no crash? why?
        free(p);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The malloc function can return anything it likes in addition to the 4x sizeof(int) bytes that you requested. But you should only use the bytes requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read or write past the bounds of allocated memory, you trigger [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

With undefined behavior, the C standard doesn't make any guarantees about what your program will do.  It might crash, it might output strange results, or (as in this case) it could appear to work properly.  In addition, making a seemingly unrelated change such as adding an unused local variable or a call to `printf` for debugging can change how undefined behavior manifests itself, as can compiling with different optimization settings.

Just because the program *could* crash doesn't mean it *will*.

All that being said, a particular implementation of `malloc` could set aside more memory than is requested, but again you can't rely on that.  The only guarantee you have is that you get exactly the number of bytes you asked for.